# System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator' does not contain any definition for 'ToList', even when referencing System.Linq

Tags: c#, .net

My code gives an error. This is the error:

`Error  CS1061  'IEnumerator' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no accessible extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

However, I am referencing System.Linq.. :

```
namespace <hidden>.Configuration
{
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Linq;

    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    using <hidden>.Configuration;

    [TestClass]
    public class ConfTest2
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCorrectConfig()
        {
            var applicationConfiguration = this.loadCorrectConfig;

            var configuration = applicationConfiguration.Configuration;
            var list = configuration.GetEnumerator().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Additionally, Resharper is telling me that System.Linq is an unused directive in the file

**Edit:** I removed the `.GetEnumerator()` call. Calling `configuration.ToList()` still gives me the same error (albeit with the type `CustomConfiguration` instead of `IEnumerable`, the `CustomConfiguration` type is an implementation of `System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection`).

The following code works (but is a rather ugly workaround for my purpose, which is checking if the list contains some element):

```
var applicationConfiguration = this.loadCorrectConfig;

var configuration = applicationConfiguration.Configuration;
foreach (var property in filter) { ... }
```

But the following code does not work

```
var applicationConfiguration = this.

var configuration = applicationConfiguration.Configuration;
var list = configuration.ToList();
```

Comment: Your description says `IEnumerable` but your question is about `IEnumerator`. The LINQ `ToList` extension is on `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerator`.

Comment: Error says it all `ToList` is not an extension of the IEnumerator<T> but `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Why are you calling `GetEnumerator`?

Comment: You may be looking for `.Cast()`, which can turn an untyped `IEnumerable` into a typed one that the other methods will actually work on. Calling `.GetEnumerator()` is almost never useful (unless you're doing some low-level plumbing/wrapping).

Comment: Why don't you just write `configuration.ToList()` ? Why call `GetEnumerator()` ?

Comment: What is the actual, concrete type of `configuration`? That could help settle this once and for all...

Comment: @JeroenMostert The actual type is a custom-made class, implementing `ConfigurationElementCollection`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos calling `configuration.ToList()` also fails, even though doing `foreach (var property in configuration) {}` does work.

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = configuration.GetEnumerator().ToList();
```

Should be.

```
var list = configuration.ToList();
```

`GetEnumerator()` returns the iterating object that steps through the sequence, including internally to `foreach` and the implementation of `ToList()`.

Comment: I missed that LINQ required a `IEnumerable` and not an `IEnumerator`. Nonetheless, doing `var list = configuration.ToList();` also fails, even though the `configuration` type implements `ConfigurationElementCollection`. Additionally, using a `foreach` works as well, but not calling `.ToList()` (to make that last part clear, calling `foreach (var property in configuration) {}` works, but calling `configuration.ToList();` does not work.

Comment: Ah. `ConfigurationElementCollection` implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>` which `ToList()` and most other linq methods require (or `IQueryable<T>`). You could though use `Cast<WhateverTypeTheObjectsAre>()` first to easily create an `IEnumerable<T>` wrapper of the appropriate `T`.